# Obj-C How to set a property on all elements of an array

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
[array makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setFoo:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

where `foo` is a public property (type `BOOL`) of the class of the elements of array. However, this is not working, and I think it has to do with how I am passing the argument, because it works fine when i loop through the array and call `[array[i] setFoo:YES]` for each element of the array. I have also tried passing `@YES` and `@"YES"`.

Comment: The method `setFoo:` takes a `BOOL` argument but you are providing an `NSNumber`. You can't do it that way.

Comment: So what' the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Key-Value Coding:

```
[array setValue:@YES forKey:@"foo"];
```

From the [docs for `NSArray`'s override of `-setValue:forKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/setValue:forKey:):

> Invokes `setValue:forKey:` on each of the array's items using the specified *value* and *key*.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
@interface Blarg:NSObject
@property BOOL flag;
@end
@implementation Blarg
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSArray *a = @[[Blarg new], [Blarg new], [Blarg new]];
        NSLog(@"Start %@", [a valueForKey:@"flag"]);
        [a setValue:@YES forKey:@"flag"];
        NSLog(@"Yes %@", [a valueForKey:@"flag"]);
        [a setValue:@NO forKey:@"flag"];
        NSLog(@"No %@", [a valueForKey:@"flag"]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Spews this:

```
2016-04-14 23:28:00.648 dfjkdf[767:101069] Start (
    0,
    0,
    0
)
2016-04-14 23:28:00.650 dfjkdf[767:101069] Yes (
    1,
    1,
    1
)
2016-04-14 23:28:00.650 dfjkdf[767:101069] No (
    0,
    0,
    0
)
```

Is it right?  Sort of.  Generally, this isn't really a pattern you should use.

You're better off doing something like:

```
    [a enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        Blarg *b = obj;
        b.flag = YES;
    }];
```

Or, better with a modern compiler:

```
    [a enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Blarg * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        obj.flag = YES;
    }];
```

It is a couple of extra lines of code, but it is pedantically type correct and, thus, the compiler will scream if the code changes in the future to break it.   Meta-programming hamstrings the compiler's ability to help you.

Comment: The enumeration can be even simpler if you declare the `obj` parameter with a type of `Blarg` instead of `id`. Then you simply do `obj.flag = YES;`.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks!  I always forget you can do that now... when we first created Blocks, the compiler wasn't capable of doing that. :)